# Run script using 'screen' with sudo privileges

Tags: scripting, sudo, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen, openvpn

I'm trying to create a script that runs in terminal is automatically started in a raspberry pi 'screen' output. The problem here is that I need `sudo` privileges inside the script, and that once the process is running I don't see the request for the password.

One example of the script is the following (if I get this to work I can adapt the script for other purposes):

1) go to a folder:

```
cd /etc/openvpn
```

2) execute the service (this requires sudo privileges):

```
sudo openvpn ./pia_netherlands.conf
```

When I enter the code manually the script does run so there is no problem there, I just have a problem executing this inside a 'screen'.

I've set up the following script using some googling:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then exec screen -dm -S pia /bin/bash "$0"; fi
cd /etc/openvpn
sudo openvpn ./pia_netherlands.conf
```

This script should check if there is a screen called 'pia' and if not create a screen called pia and run the script by firstly going to the folder and then run the openvpn file.

I've tried a second script that is a bit more straightforward but this also doesn’t work:

```
sudo bash screen -S pia
cd /etc/openvpn
openvpn ./pia_netherlands.conf
```

This script opens a bash screen called 'pia', goes to the folder, and executes the openvpn file.

Both methods are not working, and I really have difficulties finding out how to get it to run. Can anyone help me please?

I've also consulted the raspberry pi forums but no one replied, I guess because this is more of a linux question than a raspberry question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the [man page](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) correctly, `openvpn` can act as a daemon (i.e. go to the background itself) with the `--daemon` switch.

So if you don't need `screen` specifically, you might be able to go with:

```
sudo openvpn --daemon --config /etc/openvpn/pia_netherlands.conf
```

Some other alternatives:

- start `screen` to run the script, enter the password, then detach the `screen`.
- run the whole `screen` under `sudo`, instead of just the `openvpn`? i.e. 
  `sudo screen -S pia openvpn /etc/openvpn/pia_netherlands.conf`
- add the script to `/etc/sudoers` with the `NOPASSWD:` flag, so you can run that particular command without entering the password every time.

Comment: Wow that was it! What an easy solution to run it as daemon!!! I haven't thought of that thank you! I'm also going to check the screen option tough, screen seems like a very handy program to use, I'd like to understand how to use it. Thank you!